# Commandline subtitution on ksh is not being assigned to varibale

Tags: unix, less-unix

```
var2=$(echo "{$1}" | grep 'Objects that are still invalid after the validation:' | cut -d : -f2 | sed 's/ //g')
echo $var2
```

the above commandline substitution is not working ksh, the variable is blank each time, have tried below command too

```
var2="$(echo "{$1}" | grep 'Objects that are still invalid after the validation:' | cut -d : -f2 | sed 's/ //g')"
var2=`echo "{$1}" | grep 'Objects that are still invalid after the validation:' | cut -d : -f2 | sed 's/ //g'`
var2=`echo "$1" | grep 'Objects that are still invalid after the validation:' | cut -d : -f2 | sed 's/ //g'`
```

please hep me resolve the issue. The command is being used on remote server after ssh. The commands are working on the remote server if executed directly on the server without ssh.

Answer (score 0):

What is supposed to be in `$1` ? First issue is that it ought to be written as either `$1` or as `${1}`. Writing it as `{$1}` is plain wrong.

Then there is the useless use of `grep` and `cut`. The following works:

```
var2=$(echo ${1} | sed -ne 's/ //g' -e 's/Objectsthatarestillinvalidafterthevalidation:\(.*\)/\1/p')
```

Comment: $1 is an input string variable, have used {$1},"{$1}",$1 all the values and tried with simple commands but none of them are getting assigned to varibale.

Comment: Then there must be something wrong with your input. The following works without problems: `x="Objects that are still invalid after the validation: foo bar" && var2=$(echo ${x} | sed -ne 's/ //g' -e 's/Objectsthatarestillinvalidafterthevalidation:\(.*\)/\1/p') && echo ${var2}`. Output: `foobar`